# Handicapped vs physically handicapped

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference

physically handicapped Vs handicapped

What's the use of **physically** here, I know handicapped suggests illness related to body, so why I need to use **physically** anyway?

Comment: [It's right in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handicapped). Please consult a dictionary before posting here.

Comment: Because [**mentally** handicapped](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mental-handicap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Physically handicapped" means that the person's medical condition is a bodily illness, not a mental disorder or intellectual disability.

Comment: Or a component of their golf score.

Comment: …or extra weights in the horse's saddle.